# IEnumerable OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, sql-order-by

I'm using IEnumerable orderby to sort my items in ascending format but it does not work my query is like this:

```
IEnumerable<Step> steps = allsteps.Where(step => step.X <= Y);

steps = steps.OrderBy(step => step.X);
```

its not deffer to use OrderBy or OrderByDescending

why?

I want to use `Sum()` method to sum up some items and item orders is important (there are some rules)

I read in MSDN that should be enumerated to work but whats the good way (i didn't try it).

EDIT: `X` and `Y` are of type `double`.
I checked the first item of my steps (steps.First()) in quick watch.

Comment: How do you examine the result?

Comment: As you check only the first element... are you sure all elements in `steps` don't have the same X value ?

Comment: You may provide your Sum method to see what's happening, because selecting and ordering as you wrote it works with double values.

Comment: digEmAll pointed to the good note, i just have one item in my list!!! sorry to all

Answer (score 11):

First of all, why not just keep it on one line.

```
var steps = allsteps.Where(step => step.X <= Y).OrderBy(step => step.X);
```

As "vc 74" pointed out in his comment, if `X` isn't primitive or doesn't implement `IComparable` or `IComparable<TypeOfX>`then you're not going to be able to order your list, with or without LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

This just works as expected:

```
// Create some random double values from 0 - 100
var values = Enumerable.Repeat(new Random(), int.MaxValue)
                       .Select(r => r.NextDouble() * 100);

//Create an enumeration with ten elements
var pointList = values.Take(10)
                      //Cause of lacking support of IEnumerable.Zip() or .Pairwise()
                      //use this approach to create something with the properties X and Y
                      .Select(n => new PointF((float)n, (float)values.First()));

//Sort the elements
var sortedPoints = pointList.OrderBy(point => point.X);

//Output to console
foreach (var point in sortedPoints)
{
    Console.WriteLine(point.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ran into a very similar problem with this:

```
IEnumerable<Article> articles = StepThree.ReturnArticles(iUserID);
lvPending.DataSource = articles;
lvPending.DataBind();
```

Wanted to change the order the results would then bind to my listview, so I tried this:

```
lvPending.DataSource = articles.OrderByDescending(a=> a.DateCreated);
```

It executed, but didn't update my results. So looking further I discovered that because I am returning a complex type linq can't order it for me, so I had to go add the orderby descending in the StepThree.cs file where the method ReturnArticles get called.

Comment: Hi david, this question was for when I was new in linq :) it was simple mistake and it works fine, but I couldn't see it (at that time).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Since you solved your problem, it's good practice to post your solution for other people who stumble across this post.

Comment: @Matthew, You could see the comments on the question, in fact there wasn't any problem, the list has one element. I didn't delete the question because some of answer has upvote and they tried to solve the problem.